# I'm using jquery's $.Ajax method to pull json data but it won't render it to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I can get part of the data to render to the page (specifically: request, ack, and return_info) however it will not render my user data (user_id, name, session_token, photo_url). I need all user data stored to render in a table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://url/getaccount",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'account': 'all'
        },
    }).then(function (data) {
        $('.request').append(data.request);
        $('.ack').append(data.ack);
        $('.return_info').append(data.return_info);
        $('user_id').append(data.user_id);
        $('.name').append(data.name);
        $('.session_token').append(data.session_token);
        $('.photo_url').append(data.photo_url);
    });

    console.log();
});
```

Html

```
<table class="table table-striped">

    <tr>
        <td><b>User</b>
        </td>
        <td><b>Turbo User ID</b>
        </td>
        <td><b>Name</b> 
        </td>
        <td><b>Session Token<b></td>
                <td><b>Request</b>
        </td>
        <td><b>Ack</b> 
        </td>
        <td><b>Return Info<b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td class="photo_url"></td>
                <td class="user_id"></td>
                <td class="name"></td> 
                <td class="session_token"></td>
                <td class="request"></td>
                <td class="ack"></td> 
                <td class="return_info"></td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

I will be using this for several hundred users. I am not sure if I will need a for loop of not. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `data` contains an object with those keys? If it contained hundreds of users, it would likely be an array instead.

Comment: Did you add console lines/ break points and see what happens?

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't rendering? Have you debugged to see what values are being returned by your ajax call? If there are hundreds of users my first guess would be that, yes you'll need a loop, and that each `data.user`, you'll need to reference in your loop and pull its relative `data.user.user_id`, `data.user.name`, etc.

Comment: how does your sample JSON looks like ?

Comment: Yes the data contains those keys exactly. Console logs go through the all the JS with zero issues. I want the user names,id's,ect to show up in the table I created.Currently there are only a few users but that will be changing quickly.

Comment: We'll need the value of 'data' in your 'then' callback function. Also appending to an element using a class selector is also inappropriate since there will be multiple rows.. the then function callback should append an entire row to the table body.

Comment: {"request":"getaccount","ack":"success","return_code":"retrieved","return_info":"Accounts retrieved and returned successfully.","accounts":["session_token":"12c7b7c54b4a24f04a75fde83d3579448","user_id":"SgtBlinkyTest","name":"SgtBlinkyTest",{"photo_url":"http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif"]}

Comment: data.photo_url should return error as photo_url is not a field in data object but in accounts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><b>User</b></th>
        <th><b>Turbo User ID</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Name</b> 
        </th>
        <th><b>Session Token<b></th>
        <th><b>Request</b>
        </th>
        <th><b>Ack</b> </th>
        <th><b>Return Info<b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>            
 </table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://url/getaccount",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'account': 'all'
        },
    }).then(function (data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.accounts.length; i++){
            $('#myTable tbody').append("<tr>");
            $('#myTable tbody').append("<td class=\"photo_url\">" + data.accounts[i].photo_url + "</td>");
            $('#myTable tbody').append("<td class=\"user_id\">" + data.accounts[i].user_id + "</td>");     
            //etc...
            $('#myTable tbody').append("</tr>");             
        }
    });

    console.log();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.I was having a problem with it making along line but i realized it needed to be appending to the **tbody** not just the body. Thanks again!